# Is the estimate of 2 million people exiting Egypt possible?

Tags: history, exodus

[Exodus 12:37](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Exodus&chapter=12&verse=37) says that 600,000 men were led out of Egypt by Moses, leading to estimates that at least two million Israelite men, women and children were involved in the Exodus from Egypt.

Is this estimation of the number exiting Egypt (two million) during the exodus possible in view of the estimated world population at the time?

Comment: [This website](http://www.experience-ancient-egypt.com/geography-of-ancient-egypt.html) says that Egypt could have supported a population of up to 4.5 million during the New Kingdom. I couldn't find where they list their sources, but the figure gives the correct order of magnitude.

Answer (score 3):

[Exodus 12:37](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Exodus&chapter=12&verse=37) states that there were 600,000 men in the Exodus from Egypt. There must have been a similar number of women, plus children, so the estimate of two million seems reasonable, based on the Book of Exodus.

In *Ancient Egypt, Canaan and Israel in Ancient Times*, page 408, Donald Redford gives the entire Egypt population in the Late Bronze Age as only 3 to 4.5 million. If we deduct from this total, the estimated number of Israelites prior to the Exodus, then we find there could only have been 1 to 2.5 million Egyptians ruling over at least 2 million Hebrew slaves. This proportion is possible, but improbable and would require a very passive and acquiescent slave population.

If Egypt had suddenly lost around half its population, this should have had a disastrous effect on the economy and there must be evidence of this in the record. Ze'ev Herzog says, in [an extract](http://individual.utoronto.ca/mfkolarcik/jesuit/herzog.html) from Ha'aretz Magazine, Friday, October 29, 1999, that the many Egyptian documents that we have make no mention of the Israelites' presence in Egypt and are also silent about the events of the Exodus. The total silence suggests that an exodus on this scale was not possible.

Comment: I think the bigger point of contention then wouldn't so much be whether or not there could have been 2 million Hebrew slaves, but rather could Egypt could have lost half its population without documenting it, if not having its civilization destabilized altogether. This leads me to ask what functions Hebrew slaves had in Egyptian society, and in what proportion...

Comment: @DavidH I agree with you and have added a para to that effect. When I was writing this yesterday evening, I knew Herzog had written on the absence of contemporary documentation on the Exodus, but could not find it. I have now found an online extract, which enables me to cite him, with link.

Comment: I sorta figured the question had to have come up at History.SE at some point in time. Thanks for providing the Herzog link. There's also a sort of converse to this puzzle that might be more on-topic here: just as the Hebrews seem to have left no trace in Egypt, Egypt seems to have left no trace on Hebrew culture. Though I've found much less discussion of that question.

Comment: This last point by @DavidH is an excellent one.  Also on point is the suggestion that the Hebrews could not have generated such a large population over the given time period.

Comment: @Schuh Your comment "Also on point is the suggestion that the Hebrews could not have generated such a large population over the given time period. "  All the more so in the light of the fact that the Egyptians had supposedly been killing male children of the Hebrews for the last 80 years.